# Get value only when objects with same key have the same value in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java stream api, I want to get value in new set of objects only when original objects with same key have the same value, otherwise set the value to **null**. And at the same time, remove duplicate objects.

```
Set<Listing>

class Listing {
  int key;
  int val;
}
```

For example I have a set containing following instances:

```
listing{key = 1, val = a}
listing{key = 1, val = a}
listing{key = 2, val = b}
listing{key = 2, val = c}
listing{key = 3, val = d}
```

finally I want to get a set containing following instances:

```
listing{key = 1, val = a}
listing{key = 2, val = null}// because b != c as per above
listing{key = 3, val = d}
```

How do I get the result using java stream api?

Comment: It is a crazy-inefficient / complicated thing to try to do using streams ... but do it in steps.   For example.  Step 1) Convert `Set<Listing>` to `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`. Step 2) set `Map` values to `null` when `Set.size() > 0`.  Step 3) convert `Map<Integer,Set<Inte` back to `Set<Listing>`.   Are you sure that you are using the right data structure to start with??

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but maybe it will work.

```
listings.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        HashMap::new,
        ( Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map, Listing listing ) -> {
            map.computeIfAbsent(listing.key, i -> new HashSet<>()).add(listing.val);
        },
        ( Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map1, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map2 ) -> {
            map2.forEach(( k, v ) -> map1.get(k).addAll(v));
            return map1;
        },
        map -> {
            Set<Listing> set = new HashSet<>();
            map.forEach(( Integer k, Set<Integer> v ) -> {
                Listing listing = new Listing();
                listing.key = k;
                if( v.size() == 1 ){
                    listing.val = v.iterator().next();
                } else{
                    listing.val = null;
                }
                set.add(listing);
            });
            return set;
        },
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, val is a `String`, not an `int`, right?
Second, you probably want a `Map`, not a `Set`.
Here are the two solutions using streams and a simple reduce function.
It's not ready to work in parallel, however you can improve it. :)

Getting a `Map`

```
Map<Integer, String> mapping = lising.stream()
    .reduce(
        new HashMap<Integer, String>(),
        (map, lst) -> {
            if(!map.containsKey(lst.key)) {
                map.put(lst.key, lst.val);
            } else if(!Objects.equals(map.get(lst.key), lst.val)) {
                map.put(lst.key, null);
            }
            return map;
        },
        (map1, map2) -> map1 // For parallel usage - TODO
    );
```

Getting a `Set`

```
Set<Listing> set = new HashSet<>(lising.stream()
    .reduce(
            new HashMap<Integer, Listing>(),
            (map, lst) -> {
                if(!map.containsKey(lst.key)) {
                    map.put(lst.key, lst.val);
                } else if(!Objects.equals(map.get(lst.key).val, lst.val)) {
                    map.put(lst.key, new Listing(lst.key, null));
                }
                return map;
            },
            (map1, map2) -> map1 // For parallel usage - TODO
    ).values());
```

Note that both solutions only travel the initial list once, so they are very efficient.

Comment: There's no benefit to using streams over a simple loop with this solution.

Comment: The question says: How do I get the result using **java stream** api?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense that you are stating that `key` has the type `int`, but gets letters assigned to it and even worse, should be `null` in the result for certain conditions.

Changing the class to

```
class Listing {
    int key;
    String val;

    public Listing(int key, String val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Listing{key=" + key + ", val=" + val + '}';
    }
}
```

You can implement your task as

```
// Example setup
Set<Listing> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.add(new Listing(1, "a"));
set.add(new Listing(1, "a"));
set.add(new Listing(2, "b"));
set.add(new Listing(2, "c"));
set.add(new Listing(3, "d"));

// solution
ArrayList<Listing> result = set.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(l -> l.key, l -> l,
            (l1,l2) -> Objects.equals(l1.val, l2.val)? l1: new Listing(l1.key, null),
            LinkedHashMap::new),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));

// print as stated in your question
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```